# How To Load Tabs One By One

Tags: android, tabs

I have some question, I want to ask here about how to load every tabs such as:

```
One
Two
Three
```

I have this three tabs but all tabs is load in one time and in all tabs have image that load image from other website and now I want to make if I choose tabs 'One' and only tabs one load the image and other tabs not load. I have try to find some keyword that related but not found.

Comment: Since you haven't posted any code. I will assume that you are using FragmentPagerAdapter. In that case it is the default behavior.

In your case you can use FragmentStatePagerAdapter, and then use the setOffscreenPagerLimit() as suggested by Vishal. (optional)

Comment: sorry because i have no idea whats code do i put

Comment: http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-fragmentstatepageradapter-example/

Answer (score 1):

**Tabs,Viewpagers** behavior:  load its left and right side at a same time.

This is driven by `setOffscreenPageLimit()`, and the minimum value is 1, meaning that `ViewPager` will always try to create and hold onto at least 1 page on each side.
happy coding..:)